# Limit Definition to find derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x\left(1-\cos(\frac1x)\right) & x \ne 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$$

Use the limit definition of the derivative to find $f'(0)$.

Not sure how to do it but this is what I know:

The limit definition is given by the equation:

$$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

So applying that to $x(1-\cos(\frac1x))$:

$$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\left[x(1-\cos(\frac1x))+h\right]-x(1-\cos(\frac1x))}h$$

How do I go on from here?

Comment: You typed $g$ instead of $f$ and you didn't write $f(x+h)$, you wrote $f(x)+h$.

Comment: Did you mean to have  $x^2$ in the formula above in stead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to find the derivative in general, you just need the derivative at $0$. In this case,

\begin{align*}
g'(0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(h) - g(0)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h \left(1 - \cos\left(\frac 1 h\right)\right) - 0}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} 1 - \cos\left(\frac 1 h\right)
\end{align*}

Unfortunately, this limit doesn't exist.

Comment: My answer assumes that $f, g,$ and $h$ all refer to the same function.